# Half-spaces of infinite dimensional spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

It's always interesting how properties of finite dimensional objects translate (or not translate) to infinite dimension.

One can prove that for finite dimensional vector space $V$ set $\emptyset \subsetneq H \subset V$ is a hyperplane iff $H = f^{-1}(a)$ for some non-zero linear functional $f: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and some $a \in Im(f)$.

The above equivalence allows us to define term ***hyperplane*** for vector spaces of arbitrary dimension as preimages of linear functionals.

If $H = f^{-1}(a)$ and $f$ is continuous it's easy to prove that (whatever dimension space $V$ has) $H$ as well as closed half-spaces
$$ H_-(f) = \{x \in V ~~|~~ f(x) \leq a\}$$
$$ H_+(f) = \{x \in V ~~|~~ f(x) \geq a\}$$
are closed sets and open half-spaces
$$ H_{-}^{o}(f) = \{x \in V ~~|~~ f(x) < a\}$$
$$ H_{+}^{o}(f) = \{x \in V ~~|~~ f(x) > a\}$$
are open sets. Particularly this properties hold for finite-dimensional vector spaces since in this case any linear functional is continuous.

So here's my question: do this topological properties still hold in infinite dimensional spaces if we do not require the functional to be continuous? My intuition says "no" but i didn't succeed in finding counter-examples.

Comment: If $f$ is disconinuous, then $H_-(f)$ is dense but not the whole space, thus not closed.  Its complement $H_+^o(f)$ is therefore not open.

Comment: Here is an example of a discontinuous linear functional ... The space is the set of polynomials with $L^1[-1,1]$ norm; the functional is $\phi \mapsto \phi(0)$.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for your response. I need to meditate a bit over it

Comment: @GEdgar If you make an answer from your comments i'll vote for it.